# Error generating PDF document with Rmarkdown when output_dir contains spaces

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

Here is a minimal working example called *mwe.Rmd*:

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: TRUE
## header-includes:
##     - \usepackage[space]{grffile}
---

```{r}

plot(1, 1)

```
````

This will work when calling `rmarkdown::render("~/repos/mwe test/mwe.Rmd")`. However, if I call `rmarkdown::render("~/repos/mwe test/mwe.Rmd", output_dir = "~/repos/mwe test/reports/")` it fails with this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test_rmarkdown_fail.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output pandoc4f583fe0effa.tex --template /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default-1.17.0.2.tex --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' --variable 'compact-title:yes' 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.132 ...files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}
```

When I inspect the .tex file it's failing on the line to include the plot because it contains a space (between *mwe* and *test*).

`\includegraphics{/Users/savey/repos/mwe test/reports/test_rmarkdown_fail_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-1-1.pdf}`

When `output_dir` is not specified, this is just a relative path so it works fine.

Paths with spaces work fine when `latex_engine` is set to `pdftex` but not with `xelatex`. I tried to add the `space` option to the LaTeX package grffile but got an error that options clashed (with default tex template). I've also tried to modify the template to add this in the header but to no avail.

**How can I use rmarkdown with xelatex and specify an output directory containing spaces?**

Is there some option where I can force pandoc to wrap image paths in double quotes?

And before you suggest I just rename the path to remove spaces because they don't belong there (I fully agree with you), this is a synced folder I do not have the ability to rename (thank you OneDrive).

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285

Comment: Ah I see. So probably not an easy fix other than requesting a feature inside `rmarkdown` to add some "magic" intermediate step like yihui suggests here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1285#issuecomment-373141838

Comment: I ran into a problem with spaces in `output_dir` using `pdflatex`. Maybe the workaround with a temporary directory would work too. Or, relative directories, but I don't like these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above code seems indeed to work with `pdflatex`.

With `xelatex`, a workaround could be to use a temporary directory:

```
origin <- "./repos/mwe test/mwe.Rmd"
destination <- "./repos/mwe test/reports"

render <- function(origin,destination) {
  tmpdir <- tempdir()
  on.exit(unlink(tmpdir))
  rmarkdown::render(origin, output_dir = tmpdir)
  suppressWarnings(dir.create(destination))
  file.copy(file.path(tmpdir,paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(origin)),'.pdf')),destination, overwrite = T)
}

render(origin,destination)

#processing file: mwe.Rmd
#  |...................................                                   |  50%
#  ordinary text without R code
#
#  |......................................................................| 100%
#label: unnamed-chunk-1
#
#output file: mwe.knit.md
#
#/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS mwe.utf8.md --to latex --from  markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /tmp/RtmpnHeDOy/mwe.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine xelatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in'

#Output created: /tmp/RtmpnHeDOy/mwe.pdf
#[1] TRUE

dir("./repos/mwe test/reports")
[1] "mwe.pdf"
```